# How to read a list of h5 objects in a dictionary and assign them to the names said dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have the following dictionary:

```
input_dict = {'Sample': ['org_1', 'org_2', 'org_3'], 
              'Location': ['../cellbender/SAM24425933_cellbender_out_filtered.h5', 
                           '../cellbender/SAM24425932_cellbender_out_filtered.h5',
                           '../cellbender/SAM24425934_cellbender_out_filtered.h5']
                           }
```

How can I create the variables

```
org_1
org_2
org_3
```

where `org_1` is the object created by reading `'../cellbender/SAM24425933_cellbender_out_filtered.h5'`, etc.

I've tried this but get an error:

```
for sample, location in input_dict.items():
    adata = sc.read_hdf(filename = location, key = sample)
```

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Comment: "How can I create the variables" you shouldn't. Instead, use a *container* like a `list` or a `dict` to organize the results. Now, the problem you are having is how to iterate over what you want. Did you see what `.items()` is giving you?

Comment: `for sample, location in input_dict.items()` This loop gives you the first _key_ in the dictionary, `"Sample"`, and its _value_, `['org_1', 'org_2', 'org_3']`.  Then the second key and its value.

Answer (score 1):

`for sample, location in input_dict.items()` isn't what you think it is.

You will get two iterations where in the first iteration `sample` will be `'Sample'` and `location` will be `['org_1', 'org_2', 'org_3']` and in the second iteration `sample` will be `'Location'`  and `location` will be `['../cellbender/...', ...]`.

Instead, you want to extract the two lists by accessing their keys explicitly:

`input_dict['Sample']` will be `['org_1', 'org_2', 'org_3']` and `input_dict['Location']` will be `['../cellbender/...', ...]`.

Now you can use `zip` to iterate over them in parallel:

```
for sample, location in zip(input_dict['Sample'], input_dict['Location']):
    adata = sc.read_hdf(filename = location, key = sample)
```